# Limiting the number of data user can insert in database using java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

So I am making a course management system using java I completed everything but could not figure out how I can limit the number of data for a certain data.
So in my database, I have two columns: courses and modules:
[image]

So in the database, a course can have multiple modules so what I want to is that course in a semester can have only four modules and if the module is for level six students for each semester user can give Two compulsory modules and two electives(optional) modules where each level consists of Two Semesters so if the user tries to enter error message will pop up. Even a simple suggestion will be great I just need to get an idea of how I could do it. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
[image]

Comment: from the description what I understood is:
course 1 -> module1, module2, module3, module4
         if (module1, 2, 3, 4 any of these == level 6 student)
              then for each semester
                  2 compulsory subject, 2 optional

till here as fine but not very clear with the second last line EACH LEVEL CONSIST OF 2 SEMSTERS, does it mean level 6 should be considered as 11 || 12 semester

Comment: @Koushlendra so there are 3 levels(4,5 and 6) in each module where each level has two semesters 1 and 2. I have added in my question above.

Comment: Few more ques: A module is attached to 1 particular level, semester, module type and course which means module M1 can have only single level, single semester, single type and also single semester. M'I right ?

Comment: @Koushlendra yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BasilBourque

So I thought of a way to do it by using count in the database. I think I am not allowed to share my code before it is graded but I will share as much as I can.

So first I used resultset to get the count using this query `SELECT COUNT(moduleName) AS total  FROM modules WHERE courseName = ? AND level = ? AND semester = ? AND moduleType = ?;`.
So where i valid my data i get the coursename,lvl and semester from the data selected by user in my GUI from which i put the count in a integer like this:

```
ResultSet resultSet = moduleTable.getModuleCount(cname,lvl,sem,moduleType);
int count = 0;
while (resultSet.next()){
   count = resultSet.getInt("total");
}
```

Then I validated it like this:

```
if (lvl.equals("6")){
    if (moduleType.equals("Compulsory")  && count < 2){
        moduleTable.insert(mName, cname, lvl, moduleType, sem);
        count++;
    } else if (moduleType.equals("Elective")  && count < 4){
        moduleTable.insert(mName, cname, lvl, moduleType, sem);
        count++;
    } else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Compulsory subject for level 6 for each sem cannot be more than 2 and not more than 4 for elective Modules.");
    }
} else {
    if (count < 4){
        moduleTable.insert(mName,cname, lvl, moduleType, sem);
        count++;
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Each Semester cannot have more than 4 modules");
    }
}
```

I tried and it seems it works but can you give your opinion on this or if I have to correct or add something and if this answer seems correct please tell me I will mark it as the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a business rule where parent records on one table are expected to have a certain number of related child records in another table. For example, you might have a rule where an `invoice` row must have one or more related `line_item` rows, and not zero.

You can enforce that rule in at least these two ways:

- Your app checks for this during (a) data-entry and (b) data-retrieval.
- You establish a [database trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) that runs in the server automatically when inserting or updating or removing rows from those particular tables. A trigger can throw an error if the rule is violated. That error causes the transaction to be rejected.

The safest approach is to do both. Checking within the app is often more convenient, before involving the database. But if your app has any bugs there in that checking code, or admins may be altering the data outside of you app, the trigger is your fallback to make sure the business rule is observed.

Comment: someone told me I could do it by the first puting the data in an arraylist and checking data but could there be any easier way of doing it in database level?

Comment: @NutanPanta Ideally, do both: check in you app, and write a trigger. I updated the Answer to say this.

Comment: thanks I will try that even if one works and the other does not it's fine because it's for a school project and it does not have to be in such detail.

Comment: @NutanPenta Learning how to do a trigger likely will be more involved, including learning the programming language used by your database, typically a superset of SQL. Check with your teacher. I imagine if you are in a programming class you should be doing the check within your app. But if you are in a database class, you should be doing a trigger.